# CSS Drop Down Menu Not Working In Wordpress But Works On Every Other Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I've created a custom theme based on a template and for some reason the CSS drop down menu that appears on every other page when you hover of 'Services' doesn't seem to work on the wordpress page.

I copied and pasted the code I created into the Header.php file along with the same styles.

Anyone have any ideas?

The website can be fond here...

http://www.globalpurchasingsolutions.co.uk/blog/

It should work as it does here...

http://www.globalpurchasingsolutions.co.uk/testimonials.html

Any help on this matter would be very much appreciated.

Here's what the CSS Code Is Like

```
nav {
margin-top:20px;
text-align:left;
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}


nav ul {
background:#FFF;
color:#336699; 
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
width:auto;
}


nav ul:after {
content: ""; 
clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
border-bottom:solid 2px #336699;
}


nav ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
color: #2B66A2;
font-size:19px; 
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I messed around with Firebug and wasn't able to solve this.

Have you tried using 'master.css' directly in the WordPress theme instead of 'header.css' and 'style.css'?

There are various combinations of things going on, and using different stylesheets will certainly complicate things now and moving forward.

I just tried removing header.css and style.css and replacing it with master.css with Firebug... there were some other issues going on, but the dropdowns started working.